# How to play specific sound for specific number using incoming calls

Tags: android

Hi all my clients want to create a black list app in which I want to drop signals or play sound to users when call comes from that user. How can this be implemented?

Comment: hasn't android something like this built in? If I don't want to be called from certain people, i save them with a special name (:D) and give a special ring tone (like none) or assign them to a group with "special" attributes like no ring tone and no vibration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't implement such thing. Even with available workarounds, the application will break if the internal API that the workaround is based on will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, don't. No one would want an app acting like that.